# Spring boot webapp with two JPA databases

Tags: spring, jpa

I want to migrate my existing spring batch jobs to a Spring-Boot webapp using the recent version of the spring-batch-admin-manager (v. 1.3.0).

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@Import(MainConfiguration.class) @EnableTransactionManagement
public class BatchAdmin extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BatchAdmin.class, args);
  } 
  // ...
}      

@Configuration @ComponentScan("com.company.package*")
@Import({ ServletConfiguration.class, WebappConfiguration.class })
public class MainConfiguration {}

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml")
public class ServletConfiguration {}

@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"
                 ,"classpath:persistence-context.xml" })
public class WebappConfiguration {}
```

In my `persistence.xml` I configured two datasources, using two `PlatformTransactionManager` instances.
Obviously spring-boot is not able to handle such a situation by default.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,osm.transactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:337)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    //...
```

Any ideas how to override the spring-boot defaults so that I can use two datasources together?

**EDIT:** Whats weird is that despite having two different `JpaTransactionManager` beans defined the transaction aspect support seems not to have a name for the beans

```
<bean id="osm.transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="osm.entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="osm.transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="osmServiceOperation"
        expression="execution(* com.company.osm.service.spec..*Service.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="osmServiceOperation" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

The error is thrown from the `beanFactory`'s getBean method:

```
protected PlatformTransactionManager determineTransactionManager(TransactionAttribute txAttr) {
    // ...
    else if (this.transactionManagerBeanName != null) { <-- Should go here!
        return this.beanFactory.getBean(this.transactionManagerBeanName, PlatformTransactionManager.class);
    }
    else {
        return this.beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class); <-- Goes here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the datasources manually:

```
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource1() {
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

                dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
                dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
                dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
                dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

                return dataSource;
        }

            @Bean
            public DataSource dataSource2() {
                   ...

                    return dataSource;
            }
```

That way the datasource that was automaticaly configured by spring will not be available anymore.

Be careful if you autowire the datasources. You have to use Qualifier to specify which one should be used.

Comment: Both datasources are already configured in the persistence.xml, which is loaded in my WebbappConfiguration class. Isn't that enough? Well I'll give it a try ..

Comment: @achingfingers The important part is how you use the beans. If they are wired by type, spring has 2 beans of the same type and don't know what to do.